# Change column name for non-primitive field (navigation) with EF Core

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.2

Given the following classes:

```
public class Mission
{
   private MissionCard _missionCard;
}

public class MissionCard
{

}
```

I would like to create this relationship via Fluent API so that _missionCard is treated as a relationship and can be populated from DB but isn't available as a property on my Mission model.

I can create that relationship with:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Mission>().HasOne<MissionCard>("_missionCard");
```

but by default this creates a FK column named "_missionCard". The docs show that a custom name can be specified when using .Property("property name").FromField("field name") but you cannot use .Property for non-primitive types.

Is it possible to change the column name for a relationship like above?

Answer (score 0):

Managed to resolve this by inverting the relationship:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<MissionCard>()
   .HasMany<Mission>()
   .WithOne("_missionCard")
   .HasForeignKey(nameof(MissionCard));
```